# Field permission seems not working with multiple registration

Tags: 8, users

Can I use these two modules together to create a registration form and limit access to certain fields?

Module installed :

- [field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)
- [multiple registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_registration)

Wat is working ?

- The creation of the specific registration form (multiple registration)
- Set permission on field (field permissions)

What is not working ?

- When I test the form, everybody (anonymous, role x, role y, ...) can see all fieds, even the restricted one.

I hope to be a little more specific.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We love to help you. Unfortunately your question is pretty unclearn. What's "Permission field"? I can't find a module named like that. **What's your actual question?** And is this a bug report? Then you should report it over in the module's issue queue on drupal.org, not here.

Comment: Thx for your help. My question is : is it possible to set restriction/permission on fields for a specific role for a registration form. [permission field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions). The two modules I use should do what I want but not. It's maybe a bug. I'm new on Drupal.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @leymannx : thx for your help, I tried to be more precific.